# In a VB.NET Windows Forms application: How to preserve MVC when handling Events?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, model-view-controller, event-handling

I'm relatively new to Windows Forms development and my first real application has reached a point where a lot of code starts to build up in my main Form file, so I decided to restructure my project using the MVC pattern.

One major problem I have is dealing with the different control events of the form. I have several buttons, textfields, comboboxes and also a tabcontroll element which again contains different input elements and so far, every procedure for handling clicks, updates and other changes is defined in my main class.
For example:

```
Private Sub btnOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
    some code...
End Sub
```

So my question is: what would be the best way to handle these events outside of my main form? I'm more familiar with building GUIs in Java where you can use ActionListeners to achieve this but I have found nothing similar for my work with Windows Forms.

Answer (score 1):

To subscribe to a Control event outside of your main form class, make your control *public*,  so you can access from another class). This can be done using the **Modifier** property at design-time. Then, use the [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) keyword to subscribe to any event programmatically.

Comment: I tried your approach and it seems to work fine but I found it not to be necessary to make the control element public, it also works if I leave it with its default setting (friend).

Answer (score 0):

After researching a bit more, I found that there is probably not THE correct answer to this problem but I found 2 approaches which provide a solution in the way I was looking for. In both cases, I use a controller class which is responsible for handling any user interaction from my main form.

The first approach makes use of what DmitryBabich suggested, adding a handler to the object and referencing it to a method of my controller class:

in Form1:

```
Dim ctrl as new Controller(Me)
AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf ctrl.doSomething
```

Controller class:

```
Public Class Controller

    Private myForm As Form1

    Public Sub New(ByVal f As Form1)
        myForm = f
    End Sub

    Public Sub doSomething(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MsgBox("Button clicked.")
    End Sub
End Class
```

For an example this simple it is not necessary to pass an instance of Form1 over to the controller but if for example I'd like to access the values of other control elements as well, I can address them by using this instance of Form1.
For example:

```
Public Sub doSomething(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox("You clicked the button, by the way: The value of TextField1 is " & myForm.TextField1.text)
End Sub
```

The other approach is almost identical except that here the controller knows all the relevant user control objects of the form and can handle their events directly, meaning that in the main form I have to do nothing more than create an instance of the controller. In the controller however, I have to assign every user control I want to access to its own variable as soon as the main form is loaded:

in Form1:

```
Dim ctrl as new Controller(Me)
```

Controller class:

```
Public Class Controller
    WithEvents myForm As Form1
    WithEvents button1 As Button
    WithEvents button2 As Button

    Public Sub New(ByVal f As Form1)
        myForm = f
    End Sub

    Public Sub formLoad() Handles myForm.Load
        button1 = myForm.Button1
        button2 = myForm.Button2
    End Sub

    Private Sub b1Click() Handles button1.Click
        MsgBox("You clicked button1!")
    End Sub

    Private Sub b2Click() Handles button2.Click
        MsgBox("Button #2 was clicked!")
    End Sub
End Class
```